# Trouble sending mail

Tags: email, smtp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I know very little about Ubuntu but have the task of administering an Ubuntu server for our hospital intranet. The server is on a virtual machine running Moodle. Moodle sends mail fine and is set to use an SMTP IP address through port 25. However, PHP forms are not sending email properly.

I can't get either of the tests
`mail ( 'your@email.com', "Test mail", "Test mail from your server name" );`
or
`echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing someone@example.com`
to send.

I installed exim4-daemon-light but I suppose I may not have configured it correctly. I have done a `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`.

I also tried installing ssmtp but the configuration confuses me.

The server has a folder etc/postfix so I presume that is installed also, so I probably have all kinds of tools, one of which just needs to be configured properly?

After installing ssmtp and changing the config, I get the error 
sendmail: Cannot open mailhub:25

Can I get someone to help me troubleshoot this or help with the next troubleshooting step?

We have another VM that sends mail fine, but I can't find a difference in config from that one to this one - not sure where all to look though.

Comment: It looks like I figured this out.

I added the line

mailhub=10.0.0.68

to etc\ssmtp\ssmtp.conf

and that seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: Fee free to post that as an answer to your question as you will then get reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered by OP in comments**

I added the line `mailhub=10.0.0.68` to `etc\ssmtp\ssmtp.conf` and that seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't have the points to be able to do that until 7 hours later.